# structure of sigma algebra generated by a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

i don't have idea of solve this problem.

this problem from "Problems in Real and Functional Analysis by Alberto Torchinsky"

- Given a nonempty class ${\cal C}$ of subsets of $X$, let ${\cal{C}}_1=\left \{A\subset X\ ; \ A\in{\cal{C}}\ \mbox{or}\ A^c\in {\cal{C}}\right \}$, ${\cal{C}}_2=\left \{\bigcap_n A_n \ ; \ A_n\in{\cal{C}}_1\right \}$, and ${\cal{C}}_3=\left \{\bigcup_n A_n \ ; \ A_n\in{\cal{C}}_2\right \}$. Prove that ${\cal{C}}_3={\cal M}(C)$. which ${\cal M}(C)$ is $\sigma$-algebra generated by ${\cal C}$

I know structure of sigma-algebra generated by finite set.

Comment: What's the point of $C_2$?

Comment: ${\cal{C}}_2=\left \{\bigcap_n A_n \ ; \ A_n\in{\cal{C}}_1\right \}$